# Turtlebot3 blob recognition

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone! Is something here who knows a site where can I learn about blob recognition for turtlebot3? Or for robots which uses `Compressed` images data type? I search on internet but I couldn't find any.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337576/turtlebot3-blob-recognition/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You first need to decompress your image, you can do so by adding following to your launch file

`<node name="republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/compressed_image out:=/raw_image" />`

Here is one post I found for blob detection using [opencv](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) for both python and c++. You will also need [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) to convert your subscribed raw_image to opencv format.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-11-15**:
Hi! Thanks for reply! Do you have some example of code in python of how to decompress the image? I am really noob at this point so I need something concrete. Thanks!

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-18**:
you don't need code, you just add this node to your launch file and it will decompress images for you

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-11-19**:
Ok... but in my main program I will use "Compressed" msg type or "Image" ?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
I will explain it once more. Adding this node to your launch file (with correct topic) will decompress your compressed images. Then you need to subscribe to decompressed image topic of type `sensor_msgs/Image`. Now your goal is work with on image using opencv but the image you subscribed to is ros_image. So you use cv_bridge to convert it to opencv format and then you can use blob detection on it.

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-11-19**:
Thank you!! Now I understand :D

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-11-19**:
How can I see if there is something publishing? I tried to `echo` the `/raw_image` topic but nothing comes out.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-11-19**:
`rosnode list` to list all the nodes, `rosnode info /node_name` to see info of a node. In info you can see all the topics that are subscribed and are being published by node, also services